# Monitoring Azure SQL db with Telegraf and Influx

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, influxdb, telegraf

We are moving into better mechanisms to monitor our environment and we started setting up Influx + Telegraf + Grafana.

We have Azure Monitor connected to Grafana and we can see a lot of details there, but we would like to go one level deeper and get a better understanding of how our SQL is used.

I've followed the steps described here - https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/release-1.14/plugins/inputs/sqlserver/README.md.

But script is failing with next result:

```
Securable class 'server' not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

Tried to connect to SQL server with our admin account, that has all permissions and logstash is showing next results:

```
E! [inputs.sqlserver] Error in plugin: Script VolumeSpace failed: Login error: mssql: Login failed for user 'xxx_user'.
E! [inputs.sqlserver] Error in plugin: Script AzureDBPerformanceCounters failed: Login error: mssql: Login failed for user 'xxx_user'.
E! [inputs.sqlserver] Error in plugin: Script DatabaseIO failed: Login error: mssql: Login failed for user 'xxx_user'.
E! [inputs.sqlserver] Error in plugin: Script AzureDBPerformanceCounters failed: Login error: mssql: Login failed for user 'xxx_user'.
E! [inputs.sqlserver] Error in plugin: Script ServerProperties failed: Login error: mssql: Login failed for user 'xxx_user'.
E! [inputs.sqlserver] Error in plugin: Script WaitStatsCategorized failed: Login error: mssql: Login failed for user 'xxx_user'.
E! [inputs.sqlserver] Error in plugin: Script Cpu failed: Login error: mssql: Login failed for user 'xxx_user'.
E! [inputs.sqlserver] Error in plugin: Script PerformanceCounters failed: Login error: mssql: Login failed for user 'xxx_user'.
E! [inputs.sqlserver] Error in plugin: Script MemoryClerk failed: Login error: mssql: Login failed for user 'xxx_user'.
```

Could not find any issues in GitHub related to that. Is there something that I'm missing?

Did anyone succeed to connect these 2 services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement monitoring via installing a template dashboard for Influx Azure SQL monitoring - https://github.com/influxdata/community-templates/tree/master/azure_sql_db.

After installing the template, I went to the Influx UI Data menu and `Telegraf` tab.
Over there, I've copied configurations and with a proper formatting connection string, everything started working.
`YOUR_USER` - admin user
`YOUR_PASSWORd` - admin user password

Here is my connection string template:

```
Server={YOUR_DB_LINK};Port=1433;Database={YOUR_DATABASE};User Id={YOUR_USER};Password={YOUR_PASSWORD};app name=telegraf;log=1;Initial Catalog=demo;Persist Security Info=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30
```

My Telegraf configuration:

```
[[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
  urls = ["${INFLUX_URI}"]
  token = "${INFLUX_TOKEN}"
  organization = "{YOUR_ORG}"
  bucket = "AzureSQLDB"
  namepass = ["sql*"]
[[inputs.sqlserver]]
  servers = ["$AZURE_SQL_CONNECTION_STRING",]
  query_version = 2
  database_type = "AzureSQLDB"
  include_query = ["AzureSQLDBResourceStats","AzureSQLDBWaitStats","AzureSQLDBDatabaseIO","AzureSQLDBMemoryClerks","AzureSQLDBPerformanceCounters","SQLServerPerformanceCounters"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If not already, you will need to grant view definition at the database level. (without the ANY keyword)

```
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO user_name
```

Refer: SQL Server Permissions

As per Microsoft SQL Server Plugin ID: inputs.sqlserver Telegraf 0.10.1+ AAD based auth is only supported for Azure SQL Database and Azure SQL Managed Instance (but not for SQL Server), as described here.

```
 servers = [
    "Server=<Azure_SQL_Server_Name>.database.windows.net;Port=1433;Database=<Azure_SQL_Database_Name>;app name=telegraf;log=1;",
  ]
  auth_method = "AAD"
```

Additional Azure AD  authentication options available are [Active Directory Universal Authentication for SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-mfa-ssms-overview) connections including [Multi-Factor Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-mfa-howitworks) and [Conditional Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/conditional-access-configure).

Note: we have [telegraf v1.19.1 [2021-07-07]](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/releases/tag/v1.19.1) released this  8 hours ago and among its other bugfixes, this seems to be addressed:  [#9388](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/pull/9388)  `inputs.sqlserver`  Require authentication method to be specified

> But from earlier discussion on github for  telegraf release 1.10.3,
> this  works without crashing when connected as the super user (the one
> who created the whole server). It still fails when connecting as a
> less privileged user.

Other issues reported in GitHub:

- [Unable to use SQL Database in Azure with sqlserver plugin · Issue
  #4222 · influxdata/telegraf · GitHub](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/4222)
- [Adding/fixing support for Azure SQL Database (singleton database) by
  denzilribeiro · Pull Request #6111 · influxdata/telegraf ·
  GitHub](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/pull/6111)